# private vs. public typedef

Tags: c++, class, typedef, private, public

I have the following code:

```
//MyClass.h
class MyClass {
      typedef std::map<std::string, int> OpMap;
      static const OpMap::value_type opMap[OP_COUNT];

    public:
     //methods
};

//MyClass.cpp
const MyClass ::OpMap::value_type opMap[DDG::OP_COUNT] = {
    MyClass ::OpMap::value_type("hello", 42),
         MyClass ::OpMap::value_type("world", 88),
};
```

The compilation of the above code fails.
Only if i make the typdef to be public it is OK.
Can you please explain why the `typedef` should be public in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
const DDG::OpMap::value_type opMap[DDG::OP_COUNT] = {
```

should be

```
const DDG::OpMap::value_type MyClass::opMap[DDG::OP_COUNT] = {
```